# How to compare an value using xpath?

Tags: java, html, database, function, xpath

i am currently doing java and html, i have to check some values from the website against my database. i would like to ask if XPATH has such function like "is text present" or "get text = data" rather than get element, is there something to check if the value is there or something?

Comment: Usually the library you are using your xpath with provides a method getText() to get the text between your selected element.

Comment: okay i have tried that getText function. do we have to store it into a array before we can do comparison?

Comment: I don't know as I don't know what lib you are using. But usually it will give you a String which you can directly compare to a String you fetch out of your database.

Comment: alright, thank you for sharing your knowledge with me. they are valuable. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean) method in XPath.

For example, lets say your XML is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" >
<persons>
<person>
  <name>Peter</name>
  <sex>MALE</sex>
  <age>25</age>
</person>
</persons>
```

You can use the `boolean` method as,

```
boolean(/persons/person[name = 'Peter'])
```

Comment: boolean can be use too? for the method you state above what will it return? (sorry im quite new to java can't really get what it will return)

Comment: Its not Java. Boolean is an XPath method. In the above case it will return true.

Comment: ohhh okay i see. alright i will try this out also.. thanks for your comments they are valuable. thanks!